# Using standard exception class

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a standard  exception class in c++ like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a[6]={12,3,2,4,5,6};
    int n=6;
    try{
     cout<<a[6]<<"  ";

    }
    catch(std::exception & exc)
     {
         cout<<exc.what();

     }

     return 0;  
    }
```

But instead of showing me the error - "out of index"   ,it throws a run time error, saying that  the "variable a is uninitialized" ,why? I have declared it as an  array and make initialization of it. Please give me some advise why it does so?

Comment: Catch exception as const lvalue reference (const std::exception& ex) if you don't need to modify it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Accessing `a[6]` is undefined behaviour, since the only valid indices for `a` are `0`..`5`.

You shouldn't expect `a[6]` to perform any bounds checking, much less throw a C++ exception on out-of-bounds array access.

If do you want automatic bounds checking, make `a` into `std::vector<int>` and use `a.at(index)` to access its elements.

Answer (score 4):

A standard array does not check the bounds of your access. If you want a bound checking array you'd either use `boost/std::array` or `std::vector` and use the bound safe access function `at()`.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `a` to be an array of six elements; the legal indexes run from 0 to 5. The result of the expression `a[6]` is undefined behavior -- program termination is (in this case) the result. Nowhere does it say that illegal array access will throw an exception -- this is not Java!

Answer (score 2):

c++ does not check array sizes, so there is no exception thrown. If you want this check, you have to use a STL container like std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

C++ exceptions are not meant to be used to catch programming errors. They are there for run time errors like unable to open a file etc.